# Retrieving HTML element object in Python web driver

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to automate downloading of some csv files from my Splunk account. We don't have API access unfortunately.

So I thought of using [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html) Python drivers for this.

I installed Selenium and put the chrome driver in the right path.

Now the first page I want to access is the login page of Splunk as below

[image]

Here is my initial code in Python using Selenium

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

PATH= "https://splunk.com/account/login"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# Open the website
driver.get(path)


username_box = driver.find_element_by_name('username')

# Get the Password box object 
password_box = driver.find_element_by_name('password')


# Send id information for login
username_box.send_keys(USERNAME)
password_box.send_keys(PASSWORD)

# Click on the sign in button

sign_in_button=driver.find_element_by_link_text('Sign in')
sign_in_button.click()
```

It works perfectly fine until the sign_in_button driver. So it is able to open the page, enter the user name and password from the user_name and password_element, but when it comes to retrieving the Sign In element object, it's not able to retrieve the object and throws the error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Sign in"}
  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
```

Here is the HTML of the  corresponding Sign In button when I do Inspect on Chrome

[image]

So as you see it has only the class and text to it. No name and Id attribute.

So I tried first

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Sign in')
```

and then

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('splButton-primary btn')
```

but is not able to retrieve the Sign in button object.

Because of which it's not able to click and login.

Could someone help what is going wrong here with respect to retrieving the Sign in Button?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sign in` is not link text but `value` attribute, try

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[value="Sign in"]')
```

Comment: Hey quick question. Its a follow up but do u know how u got the above? Because I am trying to find the right selector for a Search button on the next page from css and not able to find the right selector. Pls see the edit.

Comment: Hey wud u be able to help with this question? I am facing some issue going further. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54154582/cannot-maintain-focus-on-element-in-selenium-python-driver

Answer (score 1):

I can't get to that site to try this out, but a couple of ideas...
First, your class name included two classes, try using just the one:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('splButton-primary')
```

alternatively, try looking for the input specifically:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input.splButton-primary')
```

Comment: Thanks. Both work. So mistake was that I was adding both the classes there.

Comment: Hey quick question. Its a follow up but do u know how u got the above? Because I am trying to find the right selector for a Search button on the next page from css and not able to find the right selector. Pls see the edit.

Comment: Magic?  ;-)  actually, it's usually straightforward once you understand how CSS Selectors work.  for the signin button, I was looking for the thing that made it a unique input element, and that was the class.  for your search button, it looks like i want to click on the link with the unique attribute for search: 'a[data-target-view=search'  (I didn't use the title attribute because that would change if we're working with a different language)

Comment: I used 'a[title="Search"]' and it didn't give the right object

Comment: Hey apparently this worked : find_element_by_link_text("Search")

Comment: But ur suggestion didn't work :( 

'a[data-target-view="Search"]'  

Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a[data-target-view="Search"]"}

Comment: Also if u cud help me with one more thing. I am learning from u. Every time I run the code, it opens a new browser window so I end up having a lot of windows. How can I make sure it works in same window and not opens new window every time

Comment: Hey wud u be able to help with this question? I am facing some issue going further. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54154582/cannot-maintain-focus-on-element-in-selenium-python-driver

Comment: you should not include the quotes around "search", and you need to keep it all lower case, just as I provided it to you: 'a[data-target-view=search]'

Comment: I went by the example by the above guy in answer and it had quotes. So felt u meant the same and probably forgot to add. 

('input[value="Sign in"]')